# Specify naming of NuGet package based on configuration

Tags: nuget, nuget-package

I have an SDK-style Class Library project (.NET 5.0) and I would like to have the generated NuGet package named based on the build configuration (*e.g.*, **MyLib.Debug.1.0.0.nupkg**). Is there some XML I can add to my .csproj file to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found it - in the `.csproj` file, in the "main" `PropertyGroup` element, add the element

```
<PackageId>My.Assembly.Name.$(Configuration)</PackageId>
```